# 'push' and 'pull' command return "push: not found"

Tags: adb, shell

I can't seem to pull or push files from my phone. The file exists, and I can get into the adb shell. But whether I do the command `adb pull` or `adb shell` and then `pull`, it doesn't work.

If I do it via shell, it gives me `'push: not found'`. If I do `adb pull` on the Windows command line, it just gives me a list of all ADB commands (so it doesn't understand push or pull).

I am using the correct syntax:

- Within shell: `push (or pull) /path/to/file`
- Outside shell: `adb push (or pull) /path/to/file`

I am working as root too.

The file I need doesn't seem to be visible to the graphical file manager I have on the phone, even though it has root permissions and is showing hidden files. It's visible via `adb`, so it's definitely there!

What's wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: You are listing the path to the file after using adb pull or adb push from Windows Command Line?  If you are just typing in adb push without anything else, you will only get a list of commands.

Comment: If you are "within the shell of Android", there is no point in using `adb` related commands and they won't work for achieving the end you're after. It's a different concept. If you are in the Windows shell than as RMarkwald says, you need to enter the full command (for `push`: both source and destination is required.)

Comment: As you question goes, you want access to a file that's only visible to `adb`, but your description seems it's visible to `adb shell` (in other words, visible to the shell of the phone itself). If you're willing to move a file within the scope of the phone storage, use the classic Linux commands `cp` and `mv` in the shell.

Answer (score 2):

By your words, I suppose that you're running `adb` **within an adb shell** and that's wrong. See [this answer](/a/167364/167409) for more details.

<sub>In case I misunderstood your question:</sub>
On Android, `adbd` is by default not running as root, so certain files and directories are not visible to the ADB client. Still, refer to [my answer](/a/167364/167409) for more details.

There is no such command as `push` or `pull` on your Android device. All you can do is `adb push` from your host PC. Whatever non-existent command makes shell tell you `aaabbb: not found` so it's not a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command from the Windows Power Shell or the Command prompt; not inside the adb shell: `.\adb pull /system/etc/hosts C:\hosts`

The `.\adb` is to show where to use the command adb from. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew this. Why though?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Use adb Directly in command prompt instead of `adb shell` use outside

```
adb  pull "/sdcard/WhatsApp Business/" "C:\Users\safva\OneDrive\Desktop\hi"
```